# How to use `Mapped[]` and `with_variant` in SQLAlquemy 2?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I used to use `.with_variant()` function, like this:

```py
    num_followers = Column(
        Integer().with_variant(
            postgresql.INTEGER, "postgresql"
        ).with_variant(
            mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True), "mysql"
        ),
        unique=False,
        index=True,
        nullable=True,
        comment="Number of followers of a user",
    )
```

But now SQLAlquemy Version 2 has `Mapped[]` ( https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping )

Is this correct to use?

```py
    num_followers: Mapped[int | None] = mapped_column(
        type_=Integer()
        .with_variant(postgresql.INTEGER, "postgresql")
        .with_variant(mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True), "mysql", "mariadb"),
        primary_key=False,
        unique=False,
        index=True,
        nullable=True,
        server_default=None,
        comment="Number of followers of a user",
    )
```

Because I feel that `Mapped[int | None]` is redundant with `type_` and `nullable`.

---

If it is correct, can I use also with datetime, like this?

```py
    created_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        type_=DateTime(timezone=True)
        .with_variant(postgresql.TIMESTAMP, "postgresql")
        .with_variant(mysql.DATETIME(timezone=True), "mysql", "mariadb"),
        primary_key=False,
        unique=False,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
        server_default=func.now(),
        comment="Date when the user was created inside the database"
    )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you use
[`with_variant`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.with_variant):

```py
from sqlalchemy.types import String
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

string_type = String()

string_type = string_type.with_variant(
    mysql.VARCHAR(collation='foo'), 'mysql', 'mariadb'
)
```

Your code:

```py
    num_followers: Mapped[int | None] = mapped_column(
        type_=Integer()
        .with_variant(postgresql.INTEGER, "postgresql")
        .with_variant(mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True), "mysql", "mariadb"),
        primary_key=False,
        unique=False,
        index=True,
        nullable=True,
        server_default=None,
        comment="Number of followers of a user",
    )
```

In `Mapped`, you define the type of `num_followers` to be an integer or None.
This can be used by a type checker to check the attribute's type.
`nullable=True` is redundant as it can be inferred from the " `| None`" in
`Mapped`.

In `mapped_column`, `__type` is used to define a more specific `TypeEngine` type
or instance to be used by the database column. This is not redundant, as both
serve their own purposes. Note that `Mapped` uses a Python type, and `mapped_column` uses a `TypeEngine`
type.

`primary_key=False` is the default, so it is redundant. `server_default=None` so
this is redundant as well. You can check the source code to see what
default values are.

So, you can just write:

```py
num_followers: Mapped[int | None] = mapped_column(
    Integer().with_variant(postgresql.INTEGER, "postgresql").with_variant(mysql.INTEGER(unsigned=True), "mysql", "mariadb"),
    index=True,
    comment="Number of followers of a user",
)
```

As for your second question, `server_default` should be set up like:

```py
server_default=text('NOW()')
```

A `text()` expression will be rendered as-is, without quotes.

Please check the documentation for more details:
[`server_default`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default)